# How to declare an external library acting like a class in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I tried to create the following d.ts file but the type for the created element is `any`:

```
declare module 'jszip' {
  interface JSZip {
    (): void
    file ( name: string, data: string, opts: any ): void
    folder ( name: string ): JSZip
  }
  const dummy: JSZip
  export = dummy
}
```

When using it:

```
import * as JSZip from 'jszip'

const zip = new JSZip ()
// zip type === any
```

What is the proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must declare your module as interface with constructor declaration.

```
declare module 'jszip' {
  interface JSZipInterface {
    (): void
    file ( name: string, data: string, opts: any ): void
    folder ( name: string ): JSZipInterface
  }

  interface JSZipConstructor {
    new (): JSZipInterface
  }


  const module: JSZipConstructor
  export = module
}
```

[image]